# Use Stateful LSTM with mini-batching and input with variable time steps, in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new in Keras, and trying to implement this network
[image]

this network takes a video frames as x = {x1,........,xT} where T is the number of the frames in the video and x is the visual features of the frames
of size 2048

i tried to use stateful LSTM as each sample have a number of frames as refereed [here](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/)

and this is my model

```
x = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 2048), name='x')
lstmR = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='lstmR', stateful=True)(x)
lstmL = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True,name='lstmL', stateful=True)(x)
merge = merge([x, lstmR, lstmL], mode='concat', name='merge')
dense = Dense(256, activation='sigmoid', name='dense')(merge)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='y')(dense)
model = Model(input=x, output=y)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and tried to train the model using mini-batching

```
for epoch in range(15):
    mean_tr_acc = []
    mean_tr_loss = []
    for i in range(nb_samples):
        x, y = get_train_sample(i)
        for j in range(len(x)):
            sample_x = x[j]
            tr_loss, tr_acc = model.train_on_batch(np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(sample_x, axis=0), axis=0),np.expand_dims(y, axis=0))
            mean_tr_acc.append(tr_acc)
            mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)
        model.reset_states()
```

but it seems like the model cannot converge as it gives 0.3 accuracy

I also tried to do it with stateless LSTM with input shape (None,1024) but it didn't converge too

Answer (score 1):

I think your LSTM is not able to extract relevant features from the video frames in order to achieve a good accuracy.

The approach that usually gives the best results when dealing with images (or video frames) is extracting features with a stack of convolution + relu + max pooling layers (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02903 which is a survey on facial expression recognition, they all use convolutions to extract useful features from images).

These work best with 2-dimensional input, but i see that you represent a video frame with an array of size 2048 instead of a matrix. Usually images are represented with a shape similar to `(rows, cols, color_channels)`.

In your case, the input would have shape `(1, None, rows, cols, color_channels)`, then the convolutions would look something like this:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, TimeDistributed, Flatten

x = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, rows, cols, color_channels), name='x')
convs = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))(x)
convs = TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(convs)
convs = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))(convs)
convs = TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(convs)
lstm_input = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(convs)
lstmR = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='lstmR', stateful=True)(lstm_input)
lstmL = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, name='lstmL', stateful=True)(lstm_input)
...
```

Where `TimeDistrubuted` applies the given layer to each time step.